# Debugging each and every code that control flows through between beginrequest to endrequest in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am not sure if I will be able to explain this clearly.

I tried to search on the internet as well but not able to find anything relevant hence the post.

I have just joined a project which is having a classic asp.net application.

There is no one to guide me and I have been told to understand the application.

So I was thinking of debugging the application right from the point where a request comes in.

I know that each request lands on `Application_BeginRequest` event in `Global.asax`.

Now, after hitting this event I want the control/debugger to go to the very next code that is getting executed (obviously not inside `Global.asax`) and so on and so forth till the time it comes back to `Application_EndRequest`.

In this way I will hopefully be able to understand the control flow and hence the application.

It is fine if it executes a lot of code and if it executes each one of them.

I am using visual studio 2010 professional.

Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: isnt F10 working?

Comment: No, F10 and F11 both just terminates the debug by the end of the event mentioned in the question. It does not go to the next executing code.